# Scala filter by extension

Tags: scala, file, filter

I have this function below for filter a list of files. I was wondering how I could filter so it only returns files that end in .png or .txt?

```
 def getListOfFiles(directoryName: String): Array[String] = {
 return (new File(directoryName)).listFiles.filter(_.isFile).map(_.getAbsolutePath)
}
```

Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a condition to `filter`:

```
(new File(directoryName)).listFiles.
  filter { f => f.isFile && (f.getName.endsWith(".png") || f.getName.endsWith(".txt")) }.
  map(_.getAbsolutePath)
```

or use `listFiles(FileFilter)` instead of just `listFiles`, but it's less convenient (unless you use experimental [Scala single method interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820352/scala-single-method-interface-implementation))

Comment: The SAM version would be something like `new File(directoryName).listFiles(file => file.isFile && file.getName.endsWith(".png") || file.getName.endsWith(".png"))`

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would filter ordinary strings:

```
val filenames = List("batman.png", "shakespeare.txt", "superman.mov")
filenames.filter(name => name.endsWith(".png") || name.endsWith(".txt"))
// res1: List[String] = List(batman.png, shakespeare.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach, a bit less verbose

```
import scala.reflect.io.Directory
Directory(directoryName).walkFilter(_.extension=="png")
```

It returns an `Iterator[Path]` which can be converted with`.toArray[String]`