# How to use ConcurrentHashMap computeIfAbsent() in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrenthashmap

I'm using a `ConcurrentHashMap` in Scala and I would like to use the `computeIfAbsent()` method but can't figure out the syntax for the second argument. Can someone show me what would be the proper syntax?

When running the following code

```
val data = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, LongAdder]

data.computeIfAbsent("bob", k: String => new LongAdder()).increment()
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Type mismatch, expected: Function[_ >: String, _ <: LongAdder], actual: (String) => Any
```

Thanking you in advance

Francis

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`, which accepts `java.util.function.Function` as a parameter for `computeIfAbsent()` instead of `scala.Function1` which you pass to it.

Since scala doesn't support lambda conversion for functional interfaces as Java does (at least not without the [`-Xexperimental` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22820352/2032064)), you can solve this by implementing a `java.util.function.Function` explicitly:

```
val data = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, LongAdder]
val adderSupplier = new java.util.function.Function[String, LongAdder]() {
  override def apply(t: String): LongAdder = new LongAdder()
}
data.computeIfAbsent("bob", adderSupplier).increment()
```

Alternatively, if you need this more often, you may write a utility conversion function or even an implicit conversion:

```
object FunctionConverter {
  implicit def scalaFunctionToJava[From, To](function: (From) => To): java.util.function.Function[From, To] = {
    new java.util.function.Function[From, To] {
      override def apply(input: From): To = function(input)
    }
  }
}

import FunctionConverter._
val data = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, LongAdder]()
data.computeIfAbsent("bob", (k: String) => new LongAdder()) // <- implicit conversion applied here
```

Answer (score 2):

If you enable `-Xexperimental` flag you can use scala anonymous function notation for this:

```
scala> val data = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String, Int]
data: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,Int] = {}

scala> data.computeIfAbsent("bob", _.size)
res0: Int = 3
```

Note that you still can't pass regular scala `Function`

```
scala> val f: String => Int = _.size
f: String => Int = <function1>

scala> data.computeIfAbsent("bob", f)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String => Int
 required: java.util.function.Function[_ >: String, _ <: Int]
       data.computeIfAbsent("bob", f)
                               ^
```

But eta-expansion will work

```
scala> def a(s: String): Int = s.size
a: (s: String)Int

scala> data.computeIfAbsent("bob", a)
res3: Int = 3
```