# How do I create a java Callable with a lambda in scala?

Tags: scala

I have this code:

```
val task = (() => {
  lineStream
    .parallel()
    .forEach(((line: String) => {
      val key = extractKeyFromLine(line)
      val random = ThreadLocalRandom.current()
      val csvRecord = gson.toJson(CsvRecordDto(random.nextInt(24), line))
      val record = new StringRecord(topic, key, csvRecord)
      val prod = producer.get()
      prod.send(record, MessageCallback)
    }).asJava.asInstanceOf[Consumer[String]])
}).asJava
pool.submit(task).get()
```

The `pool` variable is a `ForkJoinPool`. The runtime complains that `task` is a `Supplier` and not a `Callable`.

The `.asJava` thing is from `scala.compat.java8.FunctionConverters._`.

How do I fix this in scala 2.11.7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala single method interface implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820352/scala-single-method-interface-implementation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try it with explicit type ascription:

```
val task = (( () => { 
  ...your code here 
}): java.util.concurrent.Callable[Unit])
```

or

```
val task: java.util.concurrent.Callable[Unit] = () => { ... }
```

and then hope that the SAM will figure out how to convert the closure into the Callable. If SAM didn't work back in 2.11.7 (don't know, didn't try), then you can always fall back to

```
val task = new java.util.concurrent.Callable[Unit]() { 
  def call(): Unit = { ... } 
}
```

IIRC, the SAM syntax should work for version 2.11.5 and above with the `-Xexperimental` flag.

Comment: Ok, first of all, you don't provide a type parameter for callable, and intellij complains about it. Second, when I compile your second example, I get an error, saying that there's a type mismatch, found: () => Unit, required: java.util.concurrent.Callable[Unit]. The third example I can't use, it's too bureaucratic.

Comment: @hey_you Yeah, I confused `Callable` with the unparameterized `Runnable`. The syntax `val task: java.util.concurrent.Callable[Unit] = () => ()` definitely does work in 2.12. If the second proposal doesn't work in this older version, then it means that SAM is not supported, and you might have to fall back to the "bureaucratic" solution, or encapsulate it into a small helper method that takes a closure and returns a `callable`.

Comment: In 2.11 you need `-Xexperimental` scalac option (https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3018).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks! Added the hint about `-Xexperimental`. Does this now look as if it should work? Don't want to install older scala versions now, and Scastie throws some `ResolutionException`s for no apparent reason...

Comment: I think it should, but I don't have the time to check it either.